# MVC работа в контроллере с несколькими моделями.

Tags: php, mvc

Зашел в угол.

Приложение с одной точкой входа. В роутере инклудится файл контроллера и файл модели.
Также мне нужно в в каждом контроллере (читай - в родительском контроллере) получить список пунктов меню. Т.е. получается работа с двумя моделями. Неужели мне нужно в родительском контроллере инклудить файл модели меню? Есть ли еще какой способ?

Структура проекта
   http://savepic.org/5028106.htm

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужны сторонние ресурсы, не относящиеся к главной сущности контроллера. У вас есть способ получить их, не получая их? )
Ничего страшного в этом нет. Модели - это просто источник данных, и используем мы те, которые нужны. Если у вас есть блог, и нужно выводить информацию о каждом авторе, без модели пользователя же не обойтись вообще.

> Есть ли еще какой способ?

Можно в кэш запихнуть, но это будет то же самое.

Comment: То есть вы предлагаете оставить:

include 'global_model.php';

class Default_Controller{}

?

Comment: @NikolasSumrak, если я правильно понял, то у вас должна быть модель для пунктов меню, которая подключается там, где нужно. Я смотрел с точки зрения "нужно ли подключать модель меню если нужно меню", совсем по-хорошему это оформляется виджетом, а пункты меню либо статичны, либо нужна модель для их подтягивания.

Короче: у вас должны быть MenuModel, BlogModel и еще что-нибудь. Если меню у вас на каждой странице - руками MenuModel вы не подтягиваете, а оформляете все виджетом (классом, который выводите небольшой кусок html) и подтягиваете его вывод в шаблон.

Comment: А если смотреть с точки зрения:
Контроллеру нужно заюзать еще одну модель. Ее необходимо проинклудить в этом файле?
Просто не хочется автолоадер писать еще и для папки models.

Comment: То есть нам нужно получить запись в блоге и комментарии к записи в одном контроллере.
Роутером предусмотрен инклуд только одной модели:
example.com/post
инклудится в роутере Model_Post.php и Controller_Post.php

Comment: @NikolasSumrak,

> Просто не хочется автолоадер писать еще и для папки models.

По-хорошему ваш автолоадер должен выполнять только одно - подключать файл по его алиасу (см. организацию Yii) или имени. Вот приложение может использовать автолоадер, чтобы автоматом подтянуть контроллер.  
Такой автолоадер избавит от головной боли __навсегда__.

> Роутером предусмотрен инклуд только одной модели

Роутер не должен подтягивать никакие модели. Между контроллером и моделью на самом деле нет ни связи один к одному, ни один ко многим, на уровне роутера мы не знаем заранее, что потребуется контроллеру.

Comment: @Fike
просто во всех манах по mvc в php, которые я видел,  роутер тянет модель и контроллер.

У меня возникла идея: У меня есть общий класс Application. А если в него добавить статический метод App::getModel($model_name) который будет инклудить конкретную модель, это будет хорошим решением?

Comment: > просто во всех манах по mvc в php, которые я видел, роутер тянет модель и контроллер

Это вполне нормально для небольших приложений, но в них, как правило, появляется необходимость подтягивать больше одной модели.

> App::getModel($model_name)

Да, это и есть вынос ненужной логики за пределы контроллера. Идеальный вариант - это когда вы делаете new SmthModel(), а движок уже сам ищет и загружает нужный файл (если интересно то это реализуется через spl_autoload_register).

Извините, что не сразу допер, что это в учебных целях пишется.